# The three girls

Tags: logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle

A man gets to know his neighbor, and he learns that she has 3 girls. Intrigued, he asks for their age. The lady, who doesn't want to give him this information straight away, has him to take a guess.

> Lady : The product of their ages is 36.
>
> Man : I definitely need more clues...
>
> L : The sum is equal to the number of the house across the street.
>
> M : OK, so, you're not helping, uh?
>
> L : The elder one is fair-haired.
>
> M : ... Oh! I know!

**How old are the three girls, and how could the man guess it?**

---

*Not sure about my english and/or the tags (first post here, hope it is not a duplicate), so feel free to edit.*

Comment: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/208/how-do-i-tell-the-childrens-ages

Comment: @Beastly Gerbi: This is not a duplicate. In the other problem, the product is 72.  Here the product is 36. Even the solutions of the two problems are different.

Comment: @Gamow different numbers same puzzle. You solve the same issue, with slightly different information. Therefore it is a duplicate. The only thing that is different here is the surface, the underlying puzzle is the same. I'm sure IAmInPLS didn't know it was a dupe, but that doesn't mean it isn't one. Just because a solution is different doesn't mean the puzzle is

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They have to be:

> 9, 2 and 2 years old

Based on the first information, the possible ages are:

> 36 1 1
>  18 2 1
>  12 3 1
>  9 4 1
>  9 2 2
>  6 6 1
>  6 3 2
>  4 3 3

The second bit of information suggests that

> the sum of ages is not unique.
>  As the sums of the previous ages are 38, 21, 16, 14, 13, 13, 11 and 10 respectively, it means, the ages have to be either 9, 2, 2 or 6, 6, 1.

The last piece of information tells that

> there is a unique oldest child, so 6, 6, 1 is ruled out.

Comment: That's the solution !

Comment: This looks right - deleted my answer

Comment: ...except that the last piece of information does not rule out any case - e.g. $6\frac34\gt6\frac12$.

Comment: I feel that would be a bit of a stretch. Not only because it is biologically impossible for the lady to have children that close in age to each other - this is much more a math problem than a lateral thinking one. But also because it would be strange to once use the fractional part of the ages, but neglect them when calculating the sums and products. And I have the intuition, that if non-integer ages are also considered valid, there are too many (maybe an infinite number of) valid combinations.

Comment: In other words: according to the story, the man knew the ages of the children after the conversation. This would be impossible if non-integers are considered valid (for example $6+3\sqrt{2}$, $2$, $6-3\sqrt{2}$ would produce the same product and sum as $9$, $4$, $1$). So they aren't.

Comment: But I like your idea about how to extend the original problem. Further ideas that popped up in my mind (don't take them too seriously): the house number does not have to be integer; the ages do not have to be real; the man is wrong when he says, he knows the ages; the lady lies about the product of the ages; the lady lovingly refers to one of the 9-year old twins as the oldest.