# What are my sisters' ages? (With ice cream!)

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, combinatorics

This is from a book I read as a child.

> Steve said to his friend Jessica, "I have 3 sisters. The sum of their ages is the same as my age, and the product of their ages is 36. How old are my sisters?"
>
> Jessica thought for a moment before replying, "Steve, you didn't give me enough information to solve it!"
>
> "Oh, right," Steve said. "The oldest one likes Rainforest Crunch ice cream."

How old are Steve's sisters?

Comment: Hi Holly, welcome to Puzzling! Unfortunately I think your puzzle is almost exactly the same as [one we already have on this site](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/208/how-do-i-tell-the-childrens-ages), so it will probably end up being closed as a duplicate... Do take the chance to have a look around the site and see what else there is on offer here - if you think up another puzzle, try searching for keywords in the search bar to see if anything similar has already been asked. I hope you enjoy your time on the site! :)

Comment: You're absolutely right. The details are different enough that it didn't come up when I searched for it myself, though there are lots of questions about children's ages to sift through. Nice find!